# Google Chart Shows Up Locally but not on Server

Tags: javascript, html, flask, server, google-visualization

Whenever I run my app from the flask server locally on my own machine then my google chart shows up and looks great. However, when I log onto my own server and try running my app from there nothing show's up.

I have looked at the console and it does not show any errors and furthermore shows the space where the google chart should go but it is blank.

This is my code to create the chart. This is using the flask template inheritance model.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


        function drawChart() {
            var course = '{{ myFun }}';
            course = course.split(' ');
            var putInTable = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < course.length; i++){
                putInTable.push(course[i].split(":"));
            }
            putInTable.pop();

            for (var i = 0; i < putInTable.length; i++){
                putInTable[i][1] = parseFloat(putInTable[i][1]);
            }
            putInTable.unshift(["courseName", "overlap"]);

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(putInTable);

            var options = {title: "Visualization of Overlap"};
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to figure out where it stems from, e.g. what's the value of `var course`, is there any network errors.

Comment: How do I find out if there are any network errors? I've looked at the console and that didn't show anything? Also I don't think there should be anything wrong with var course because the code works locally.

Comment: There must be something wrong, right? You can first check front end side in your browser, e.g. with Chrome DevTools to find out if there are any errors, if you haven't done that yet.